# How to extend width window of my png output

Tags: r, plot, png

I want to make a dual y-axis graph that gives the absolute number change on the left hand side of total enrolment and female enrolment, and the proportion of female enrolment on the right hand side.

I've gotten the code to output the graph I want into png, but it doesn't fit within the window. I've tried expanding the size of the output file but that just enlarges the output instead of extending the window.

```
png("UNDERSTEM1.png", width=700, height=700)
plot(x, y1, type = "b", frame = FALSE, pch = 20, 
     col = "black", xlab = "Year", ylab = "", ylim=c(0,11000000))
mtext("No. of Students", side=2, line=3)
lines(x, y2, pch = 20, col = 451, type = "b", lty = 1)
par(new = TRUE)
plot(y5, type = "l", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n",
     ylab = "", xlab = "", col = "red", ylim=c(0,100), lty = 2)
axis(side=4, seq(0, 100, 10), las=2)

mtext("Percentage", side=4, line=3)

legend("topleft", legend=c("STEM", "STEM FEMALE", "PERCENTAGE FEMALE"),
col=c("black", 451, "red"), lty=c(1, 1, 2), cex=1)
dev.off()
```

The output of this is a graph that has the percentage values on the right-hand side like I want, but it cuts off the end of the last 0 on 100 and doesn't show the percentage label either.

Comment: `par(mar=c(5,4,4,4))` (before your first `plot`) might be a first step, see [`?par`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.1/topics/par) for details.

Comment: Thanks, got it. I tried that the wrong way.